# Using SUMIF to add up cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel i have a data like

```
E_ID   EC ID  Rate   Enum   total_Rate
1004   1001   12.3
1004   1001   2.2
1004   1001    1       
1004   1001   5.8    1004         
1142   1001    3
1142   1001   2.1
1142   1001    1     1142
1166   1001    0  
1166   1001    0
1166   1001    4
1166   1001    6
1166   1001    4
1166   1001    1      1166
```

For 'ENUM' column i'm using **=IF(A3=A4,"",A3)** formula and getting 'Enum' value for eq: 4 consicutive EID=1004, 'ENUM' displays 1 time and for 'total_rate' column i need to sum 'Rate' if EID's are same eg : for 1004 sum is 21.3. And result looks like

```
E_ID   EC ID  Rate   Enum   total_Rate

1004   1001   12.3    
---------------------------------------
1004   1001   2.2
---------------------------------------
1004   1001    1  
---------------------------------------     
1004   1001   5.8    1004     21.3  
---------------------------------------      
1142   1001    3
---------------------------------------
1142   1001   2.1
---------------------------------------
1142   1001    1     1142     6.1 
---------------------------------------
1166   1001    0  
---------------------------------------
1166   1001    0
---------------------------------------
1166   1001    4
---------------------------------------
1166   1001    6
---------------------------------------
1166   1001    4 
---------------------------------------
1166   1001    1      1166     15 
---------------------------------------
```

How do i specify the formula SUMIF in the 'total_Rate' column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want it to show on any other row. Starting at field E2, and then down the E column;

`=IF(A2<>A3,SUMIF(A:A,A2,C:C),"")`

That should give you the desired result.